# PHP - Formula doesn't want to post with image

Tags: php, image, submit

y0 c0derz!

My formula looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?sida=upl" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform">

        <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" class="file_1" />
        <input type="image" name="submit" style="margin-left: 120px;" src="uplbutt.png" />

</form>
```

And the PHP code for the formula looks like this:

```
if (array_key_exists('image', $_POST)) 
{
// do something here bla bla
}
```

But when i click on the image-submit button nothing happens as it is suppose to happen? What could be wrong?

Comment: there is no field in your form named "image". Is this an error in your question or is it really in your code? If it's in your code and what's supposed to happen is inside the `if` block then it's normal that nothing happen.

Comment: When i click on the image-submit then it is going to upload the file. So i have a upload function inside the if-block. But no file is uploaded. But when i use a regular submit button it works, when i replace the "image" to "submit" inside the array_key_exists.

Comment: by "formula" are you referring to the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image inputs are sent as (x, y) coordinates, like [name].x and [name].y.

Since these aren't valid PHP variable names, the points are replaced by underscores, so you need to look for:

```
if (array_key_exists('image_x', $_POST))
```

Answer (score 0):

The key in the `$_POST` superglobal will not be the "`type`" attribute of the input of the form, but it's "`name`" attribute -- or something based on its name, depending on the input's type *(for an image input, there should be `image_x` and `image_y`, if I remember correctly)*.

To get a dump of what is POSTed, you can use, for instance :

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

This will show you which variables you can use on the PHP side.